# Loop inside stored procedure doesn't stop after query cancellation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a few nested stored procedures, which have a while loop at the end. When I stop the query, the loop keeps running, though. Every child sp is independant from another and has a duration of less than 1s. Any ideas why it keeps running or how to properly cancel it?

Comment: It would be better if you add code too. So maybe we could find out whether query do have problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at running requests with either [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) or with the below query and kill the session associated with the query / stored procedure.

```
select r.session_id
    , s.text
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s
```

Then you just execute the `KILL` command, like below, with the appropriate integer value from the above result, session which is associated with your stored procedure / query:

```
KILL <session_id>
```